# jQuery Dialog Close Event not working as expected

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to create a popup dialog with CodeBehind Events and JavaScript events.  I have created a button that launches the following dialog.  That works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowDialog(aPage, aWidth, aHeight, aTitle) {
        var $popupURL = aPage;
        var $popupDv = $("#resultDiv");

        jQuery.ajax({ url: $popupURL,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $popupDv.empty().append(html);

                $popupDv.dialog({
                    width: aWidth,
                    height: aHeight,
                    modal: true,
                    title: aTitle,
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false
                });
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Button Code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div id="resultDiv">
    </div>
    <input id="Edit1Button" type="button" value="Edit 1" onclick="ShowDialog('edit3.aspx?ID=1', 600, 400, 'Hello Edit 1')" />
</div>
</form>
```

Keep in mind this is just test code..  OK so after I click the button a dialog pops up.  In the dialog, I have the following code..

```
<form id="form2" runat="server">
<div>
    <h1>
        Edit Dialog 3</h1>
    <asp:Button ID="CloseButton" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClick="CloseButton_Click"
        OnClientClick="$('#resultDiv').dialog('close'); return true;" />
</div>
</form>
```

if I have return false, then just the javascript OnClientClick fires and the dialog closes..  Works as expected.  if I set return true the dialog closes but this is where the issue is.  the main form disappears and is replaced by the dialogs form..

I need this button to execute the CloseButton_Click in codebehind then close the dialog.  I am VERY new to asp.net and C# so be gentle with your responses.. like weeks

Thanks
Anthony

Comment: Both of your forms have the same ID. That's a no-no.

Comment: Sorry..  I renamed the form in edit3 to form2..  this was just a quick sample i put together.. that was an oversite..  Still doesn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that since your child form (Edit3.aspx) is posting back to the webserver, ASP.NET is sending back the response for Edit3.aspx - not your initial form. In order to accomplish what you want, you will have to use an asynchronous postback to the server. This can be accomplished by changing your Edit3.aspx form to the following:

```
<form id="form2" runat="server"> 
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div> 
<h1 runat="server" id="edit3"> 
    Edit Dialog 3</h1> 
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="CloseButton" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClientClick="$('#resultDiv').dialog('close'); return true;" /> 
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

The ScriptManager control and the UpdatePanel control allow your form to post back to the server asynchronously.

Comment: OK... I am halfway there...  Is there a way to have an event fire when the dialog closes.  Keep in mind that the event will have to be passed to the ShowDialog() since I will be calling that function from several places.

Comment: Do you want the event to fire a CodeBehind event? And on which page - edit3.aspx or the parent form?

Comment: parent form.. I have the CodeBehind firing on Edit3..  I need to do a partial update when the dialog returns.

Comment: I think that you can add the following to the OnClientClick of the CloseButton: _doPostBack('_Page', 'MyCustomArgument'); -- see this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738327/how-to-call-postback-using-javascript-on-asp-net-form

Comment: I have modified my button, maybe I am doing this wrong.. <asp:Button ID="CloseButton" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClick="CloseButton_Click"
                    OnClientClick="$('#resultDiv').dialog('close'); return true; _doPostBack('_Page', 'UpdateGridView1');" />  UpdateGridView1 is a function in CodeBehind

Comment: Ok -  email it to me. I'm at work right now but I'll look at it tonight.

Comment: here is a link to the sample app running [Sample App Running Link](http://www.connectixbusiness.com/GridViewProblem.aspx) and here is a link to the source files [Sample Source Code Link](http://www.connectixbusiness.com/AddEditGridViewSolution.zip)...  Thank you and I appreciate you looking at this..

Comment: ok - i tried to get your code last night but your site was down.